# What type of electrical sensing element is used in Water Quality Monitoring Meters?

Tags: sensor

What type of **electrical** sensing element is used in Water Quality Monitoring meters such as those pictured below? I might not be using the correct search terms.

[image: Water-Quality Meter 1]
[image: Water-Quality Meter 2]
[image: Water-Quality Meter 3]

Some of these meters monitor Total Dissolved Solids (TDS) or pH levels in water.

I suspect there is an electro-chemical sensor. I have not been able to locate any information on the **electrical** sensing element or the mechanism. I intend to build a simple water quality meter using a simple microprocessor and respective sensing element.

Note: I posted this question on [Engineering](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/511/what-type-of-sensing-element-is-used-in-water-quality-monitoring-meters). I am looking for type of electrodes and possible sensing circuitry use in such a device.

Comment: There may be more than one measurement going on.  Temperature and AC conductivity and ...?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice [write up](https://phidgets.wordpress.com/2015/01/13/specialized-sensor-series-2-water-quality-sensors/) of how some common water quality sensors work.  They cover conductivity used to measure tsd, ph and dissolved oxygen.   Should be a good start.

This [link](http://www.iccontrols.com/files/TDS_Measurement.pdf) gives more info on how conductivity is related to tsd.